# Read an object variable having "FileInfo" object content in C# script task

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, ssis, ssis-2012

I'm trying to loop and read an object variable(as shown in the pic) where it has the file details(name/size/datemodified) from a share point location.

[image]
Basically I need something similar to below code to just read the "Name" value.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public void Main()
        {

            var fileinfo = Dts.Variables["User::DvarObj"].Value;
            Dts.Variables["User::Local"].Value = new List<String>();
            List<String> OutputFileNames = (List<String>)Dts.Variables["User::Local"].Value;
            var collection = fileinfo as IEnumerable;


            if (collection != null)
            {

                foreach (var item in collection)
                {

                    OutputFileNames.Add(item.GetType());
                }
            }


            var id = fileinfo.GetType().Name;

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }
```

I'm not sure how to get the "Name" field value added to the list. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: It seems you have object array {object[2]} with two elements. Therefore, you can do foreach. However, if you want to just use first element  Filename = fileInfo[0].Name will give you the file name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is a type where we have objects containing objects values. So to access this please use the below method.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;
using System.Xml;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
    public void Main()
        {

            var fileinfo = Dts.Variables["User::DvarObj"].Value;
            Dts.Variables["User::Local"].Value = new List<String>();
            List<String> OutputFileNames = (List<String>)Dts.Variables["User::Local"].Value;
            string outputresultnames = "";
            foreach (object element in (fileinfo as IEnumerable ?? Enumerable.Empty<object>()))
            {
                var type = element.GetType();
                var props = type.GetProperties();
                object result = props.First().GetValue(element, null);
                outputresultnames = (string)result;
                OutputFileNames.Add(outputresultnames);
            }

            Dts.Variables["User::Local"].Value = OutputFileNames;

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }
```